# How do I get m or b column specifiers working?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have quite simple example:

```
\documentclass[9pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{PTSerif}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| m{1cm} | p{5cm} | b{1cm} |}
\hline
boo &
b dlkf jsdklfjsdlfkjas;l fjsdlk fjasldfj;lskd fjalskjalk jslk jlska jlksa     jflskd jfalk jlsk jlksa jlsk jf;asjlaksjl;askj;alskjsalk jlsak &
boo \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And it appears that m or b specifiers don't work as expected (they are located on top of a cell not in the middle or at the bottom).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| m{1cm} | p{5cm} | b{1cm} |}\hline
boo b dlkf jsd klfj sdlfk jas;l 
  & fjsdlk fjasldfj;lskd fjalskjalk jslk jlska jlksa   
  &  jflskd jfalk jlsk jlksa jlsk jf;asj laksjl; askj;alsk jsalk jlsak boo \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The m-cell is centered to the first line of the p-cell and and the b-cell has its
bottom on the baseline of the first line of the p-cell. look at the output of my example:

[image]

Comment: But what if I need alignment centered to the whole paragraph and not only the first line?

Comment: then also use the m column specifier instead of a p column

Comment: a bit unintuitive for me but looks like it works, thanks